# Search query function in PHP

Tags: php, facebook, string, api

I've hit a bit of a snag. I'm busy building a search function for my social networking privacy awareness site. The search will query the Facebook Graph API as you can do using https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=i hate my boss&type=post&limit=100&locale=en_GB my issue is that I want to put quotes around the query so when the user types into the text field and hits the search button the php code does the rest and queries the API but at the same time will query it like https://graph.facebook.com/search?q="i hate my boss".

Question is how do I do this? My code is only partial to keep it to the point of where it is:

```
$str = $_REQUEST['query'];
$str = urlencode($str);
$fbquery = "https://graph.facebook.com/search?q={$str}&type=post&limit=100&locale=en_GB";
```

Obviously I'm asking the question of where or how would I put the quotes in there ?

Anyone that could help me with this I'd very much appreciate it! I have tried other things like:

```
$str = '".$str."';
```

or

```
$str = '"$q"';
```

but none have worked. Please help!

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: The things you have tried clearly suggest a missing knowledge of some very basic PHP syntax issues. You should try to beef up your knowledge on these basics before continuing to work with the FB API. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 1):

Since you are passing the query string via GET in the url, you should need to encode the query before you pass it in the url.

the php [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) function does this.

so instead of:

```
y = "https://graph.facebook.com/search?q={$str}";
```

you need to

```
$encoded_str = urlencode($str);
y = "https://graph.facebook.com/search?q={$encoded_str}";
```

example:

> https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=good wine

vs.

> https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=good%20wine

where in the second example,    is translated into `%20`

Answer (score 1):

try this. it's simple.

$str = '"'.$str.'"';

Answer (score 0):

I think adding the quotes **before** the `urlencode` should work. Also consider using the [http_build_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) function, that should give you valid query string results, and a little more readable.

```
$params = http_build_query(array(
    'q' => '"'.$str.'"',
    'type' => 'post',
    'limit' => 1000,
    'local' => 'en_GB',
));

print 'https://graph.facebook.com/search?'.$params;
```

In my testing adding the quotes doesn't change the results, returned from Facebook tough.

Answer (score -1):

How about this:

`$fbquery = "https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=\"{$str}\"&type=post&limit=100&locale=en_GB";`